# tag-wiki editing confusion

Tags: support, tag-wiki, help

It's a bit misleading to see

> the [tag name] tag has no wiki summary, can you help us create it?

from where you are greeted with the tag info, however from here you are stuck and there is no way to know what the next step is (if there is one).

Tim Has explained that this is because someone has beat me to the action however there is no real way of telling wether this has happened or not.

- On the Tag info:

---

[image: taginfo]

---

- Clicking on either of these buttons didn't help either:

  (clicking on 'edit pending' simply sends me to [stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits))

---

[image: buttons]

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tag wiki edits need to be approved for users who have less than 20k reputation, and based on your screenshot ("edit pending") it looks like there's an edit for that tag wiki awaiting approval at this time.

Clicking the "edit pending" link will show you the current suggested edit if you have enough reputation to vote on it, or [the relevant privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) if you don't. Until that suggested edit has been either approved or rejected, you won't be able to submit your own edit suggestion to that tag wiki.

Comment: It's a bit confusing seeing the difference between editing one and 'proposing' one but I think i get what you're saying, so by 'propose new tag wiki' what it really want me to know is that any user may *edit* a tag wiki?

Comment: Also, clicking on 'edit pending' simply sends me to http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits

Comment: Ah, it must take you there if you don't yet have the privilege to approve the tag wiki edits.

Comment: I feel as though this needs to be revised; or by removing the line 'All registered users may propose new tag wikis.' from the info box.

Comment: All registered users can propose tag wikis, though. You just can't in this particular case because someone beat you to the punch and hasn't had their proposal reviewed yet.

Comment: Ohh okay then, well some notification of this case would be nice. Thanks for the info :)